# ASP.net MVC - Binding a form value to a different name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a View that has the ability to both create and edit an item that I have separated into partial views:

```
MainEditView.cshtml
_CreateChildDialog.cshtml
_EditChildDialog.cshtml
```

I have separate ViewModels for both the Create and Child items:

```
public class CreateChildViewModel
{
    public string ItemText { get; set; }
}


public class EditChildViewModel 
{
    public string ItemText { get; set; }
}
```

Since the partial views for the Edit and Create dialog boxes will both be rendered on the same page, I will have a conflict for form id's and names...since they are both called ItemText.

Is it possible to customize the binding of these elements without writing a custom model binder?

I would like to do something like:

```
public class EditChildViewModel
{
    [BindFrom("EditItemText")]
    public string ItemText { get; set; }
}
```

Or does it just make more sense to rename the ViewModel properties to:

```
public class EditChildViewModel 
{
    public string EditItemText { get; set; }
}

public class CreateChildViewModel
{
    public string CreateItemText { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT**
Based on converstation with Darin I want to make this a little more clear.

My Parent has an Edit action.
When you edit the Parent, you would never create a new child or edit a child when you are calling the ParentController.Edit action.

I have a separate controller for the Child object that has a Create and Edit method:

```
public class ChildController 
{
    public ActionResult Edit() {}
    public ActionResult Create() {}
}
```

I am using jQuery calls to asynchronously post to this controller when you edit or create a child. Basically I use a jquery dialog to create/edit a child that will get saved immediately when I click Ok on the dialog. This would happen even before clicking save for the Edit action of the parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use editor templates. Normally you would pack those two view models into a main view model which will be used by the main view:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public CreateChildViewModel Create { get; set; }
    public EditChildViewModel Edit { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Create)
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Edit)
```

and I would replace the two partials by their corresponding editor templates (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/CreateChildViewModel.cshtml` and `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/EditChildViewModel.cshtml`). The editor templates will take of generating proper names and ids of the corresponding input elements.

Personally I tend to prefer editor/display templates instead of partials as they handle better naming of input elements.

Comment: Does this still apply if the CreateChild / EditChild calls are being made separate from the parent? I'm using a jquery AJAX call to submit it to a different controller than the "parent" item.

Comment: @Dismissile, so the actions you are posting to take respectively `CreateChildViewModel` and `EditChildViewModel` as arguments? In this case you could specify the prefix so that the default model binder can successfully bind it: `public ActionResult Create([Bind(Prefix="Create")] CreateChildViewModel model) { ... }`.

Comment: Yes. In my case, you would never save a Parent along with a child. I will update my post to more clearly reflect this.